# How to render Hindi font on HTML5 android app

Tags: android, html, fonts, indic

I am trying to Create an HTML Android app in Hindi but I am unable to get font working, font is working fine on browser but not working in android 
I am having lenovo-a1-07 and 2.3 version creating app using phonegap and jquerymobile.

I have tried all the SO previous suggestions
Used meta tag UTF-8
tried copying font in font directory and use it
tried rooting device and coping font in system/fonts directory 
Also tried unicodes for hindi fonts like "ऄ"

nothings seems helping me please suggest what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing fontoosh (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.technoguff.fontoosh&hl=en) resolve my issue. Now Browser and APP both displaying Hindi Character properly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **webfonts**

Check links below :
http://www.brianhadaway.com/font-face-declarations-on-android-devices/
http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Droid+Sans

or generally search for **webfont on android**